# UPDATE with INNER JOIN or MIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to transfer some data between tables.  The 'NEW' table can have multiple entries of the data that was originally not meant to have multiple entries in the 'OLD' table.  I would like to take the data from the 'OLD' table and copy it over to the new table where the NEW.ID is the lowest where new.OtherID=old.OtherID, basically a MIN(ID) per group of OtherID's equal to each other.

'NEW' table

```
ID | OtherID | Data
1       1      NULL
2       1      NULL
3       2      NULL
4       3      NULL
5       3      NULL
```

'OLD'

```
OtherID | Data <br>
1            data1
2            data2
3            data3
4            data4
5            data5
```

Desired Outcome on updated 'NEW' table:

```
ID | OtherID | Data <br>
1       1       data1
2       1       NULL
3       2       data2
4       3       data3
5       3       NULL
```

etc

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you could use INNER JOIN with [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) in MySQL:

```
UPDATE NEW n
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      OtherID,
      MIN(ID) AS ID
    FROM NEW
    GROUP BY OtherID
  ) m ON n.ID = m.ID
  INNER JOIN OLD o ON n.OtherID = o.OtherID
SET n.Data = o.Data
```

Comment: Putting the subquery in the JOIN makes this much more readable than the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
UPDATE new
   SET Data = ( SELECT DATA FROM old WHERE otherID = new.otherID )
 WHERE NOT EXIST
       ( SELECT NULL FROM new AS new2
          WHERE new2.id < new.id
            AND new2.otherID = new.otherID )
```

Note that this is standard SQL92 and should work with any RDBMS.

Comment: I'm getting error #1093, You can't specify target table 'new' for update in FROM clause

Comment: That's because it's also part of a subquery, I'm starting to think you may need to do it in a PHP (or similar) script...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in PostgreSQL, though I may have gotten the quoting wrong for MySQL.

```
UPDATE newtable SET
 `Data` = oldtable.`Data`
FROM
 oldtable
WHERE
 newtable.`ID` IN (
  SELECT MIN(sub_newtable.`ID`)
  FROM newtable sub_newtable
  GROUP BY
   sub_newtable.`OtherID`
 )
 AND newtable.`OtherID` = oldtable.`OtherID`
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
UPDATE `NEW` 
LEFT JOIN `OLD` 
    ON `NEW`.`OtherID` = `OLD`.`ID`
SET `NEW`.`Data` = `OLD`.`Data`
```

EDIT: I'm sorry, this will update all records that correspond to columns in OLD.